# I keep getting an unexpected data type error when trying to append to an excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

In my code, I created a new excel sheet and want to add the data in my python dictionary into my excel cells. However, I keep getting an unexpected data type error.

```
#this creates a new workbook call difference
file = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/vhim/Documents/Exception_Cases/Orders.xls')
wb = xl_copy(file)
Sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('differences')

#this creates header for two columns
Sheet1.write(0,0,"SO_Numbers")
Sheet1.write(0,1,"Booking Values")

#this would store all the of Key, value pair of my dictionary into their respective SO_Numbers, Booking Values column
#I want SO_Numbers column to add the Key data and Booking Values columns to add the value data
print(len(diff_so_keyval))
rowplacement = 1
while rowplacement < len(diff_so_keyval):
    for k, v in diff_so_keyval.items():
        Sheet1.write(rowplacement,0,k)
        Sheet1.write(rowplacement,1,v)
        rowplacement = rowplacement + 1

This is what I have in my diff_so_keyval dictionary 

diff_so_keyval = {104370541 [31203.7]
106813775 [187500.0]
106842625 [60349.8]
106843037 [492410.5]
106918995 [7501.25]
106919025 [427090.0]
106925184 [30676.4]
106941476 [203.58]
106941482 [203.58]
106941514 [407.16]
106962317 [61396.36]}

 4     for k, v in diff_so_keyval.items():
      5         Sheet1.write(rowplacement,0,k)
----> 6         Sheet1.write(rowplacement,1,v)
      7         rowplacement = rowplacement + 1

Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'float'>
```

Comment: *Don't* use the obsolete `xls` format unless you really really need to handle Excel 2003. This was replaced by the xlsx format 13 years ago. Even Office Online and Google Sheets doesnt' support it in their free version. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files, it's well-defined while `xls` *isn't*, smaller, easy to manipulate with libraries

Comment: so will using a xlsx solve that issue ?

Comment: I don't know - which libraries are you using? `openpyxl` doesn't use `write` - you use the address directly, eg `sheet["A1"]` or use the `cell` functin. `xlrd` only reads and doesn't have any maintainers anyway. Only `xlwt` has a `write` but that's the only tag missing. `xlwt` doesn't support `xlsx`

Comment: What does `v` contain? How do you create `diff_so_keyval`?This error is too basic - if `xlwt` didn't support float nobody would use it. You should be able to reproduce such a problem with `Sheet1.write(0,2,1.5)`. That would contradict the docs *and* the tests though and make the library completely useless.